# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(), intenção Html to Txt (no mínimo), alguém pode ajudar?

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou recebendo um registro cujo conteúdo é este abaixo (em HTML):

```
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: times new     roman,times;"><span style="font-size: medium;"><strong>EDECPJE N&ordm;    </strong> <strong>0800141-19.2014.4.05.0000 - AGTR</strong></span></span></p>
(...)
```

Mas preciso salvar isto em TXT (no mínimo, o ideal era converter as formatações e salva tudo).

Feliz, tentei utilizar o HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(), mas para minha decepção ele apenas removeu o `&nbsp;` entre outras tag inexpressivas.

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isto de forma correta?

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Comment: A tua pergunta não é muito explicativa, o que dificultará você a ter uma resposta que resolva o problema. Coloque o resultado esperado do trecho do HTML que você postou. Você está ciente que `&nbsp;` representa *espaço sem quebras*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Amigos, obrigado pelo empenho. Encontrei uma solução satisfatória que demonstro abaixo:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Esse comando não vai formatar nada, apenas remover todas as tags (HTML/XML) de modo rápido e simplificado. Se encontrar uma solução mais elaborada (tipo além de remover tudo, manter a formatação) eu posto aqui.

Mais uma vez obrigado.